# how to extend a protocol for a delegate in objective C, then subclass an object to require a conforming delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates

I want to subclass UITextView, and send a new message to the delegate. So, I want to extend the delegate protocol.  What's the correct way to do this?

I started out with this:

interface:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class MySubClass;

@protocol MySubClassDelegate <UITextViewDelegate>
- (void) MySubClassMessage: (MySubClass *) subclass;
@end


@interface MySubClass : UITextView {
}

@end
```

implementation:

```
#import "MySubClass.h"


@implementation MySubClass

- (void) SomeMethod; { 
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector: @selector (MySubClassMessage:)]) { 
        [self.delegate MySubClassMessage: self];
    }
}

@end
```

however with that I get  the warning: `'-MySubClassMessage:' not found in protocol(s)`.

I had one way working where I created my own ivar to store the delegate,  then also stored the delegate using `[super setDelegate]`  but that seemed wrong.  perhaps it's not.

I know I can just pass id's around and get by, but My goal is to make sure that the compiler checks that any delegate supplied to MySubClass conforms to MySubClassDelegate protocol.

To further clairfy:

```
@interface MySubClassTester : NSObject {

}

@implementation MySubClassTester

- (void) one { 
    MySubClass *subclass = [[MySubClass alloc] init];
    subclass.delegate = self;
}

@end
```

will produce the warning: `class 'MySubClassTester' does not implement the 'UITextViewDelegate' protocol`

I want it to produce the warning about not implementing 'MySubClassDelegate' protocol instead.

Comment: updated with more example code to further clarify,  brad made it clearer to me that the `'-MySubClassMessage:'  not found in protocol` was not actually in indicator that the compiler was checking that the delegate was of a correctly conforming type.  and that @optional I had for MySubClassMessage made the question almost moot. ;)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `UITextView` defines its `delegate` as

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<UITextViewDelegate> delegate
```

meaning it conforms to `UITextViewDelegate`, and that's what compiler checks. If you want to use the new protocol, you need to redefine `delegate` to conform to your protocol:

```
@interface MySubClass : UITextView {
}
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<MySubClassDelegate> delegate   
@end
```

The compiler shouldn't give any more warnings.

**[Update by fess]**

... With this the compiler will warn that the accessors need to be implemented... [I implemented this:]

```
-(void) setDelegate:(id<MySubClassDelegate>) delegate {
[super setDelegate: delegate];
}
- (id) delegate {
return [super delegate];
}
```

"

**[My update]**

I believe it should work if you only make a `@dynamic` declaration instead of reimplementing the method, as the implementation is already there:

```
@dynamic delegate;
```

Comment: thanks. With this the compiler will warn that the accessors need to be implemented.   though they are there in the superclass.  I previously failed to implement these, and that drove me to storing the delegate in my own ivar.  however I've tried again given you recommendation, and that did it.   can you add these too your answer   so they get formatted nicely:  `- (void) setDelegate:(id<MySubClassDelegate>) delegate { 
    [super setDelegate: delegate];
}

- (id) delegate { 
    return [super delegate];
}`

Comment: @dynamic delegate. does work.  thanks a bunch, I understand things much better now.

Comment: Turns out you don't need to redefine the delegate! See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732701/how-to-extend-protocols-delegates-in-objective-c

Answer (score 7):

For anyone still interested, this can be done quite simply like this (for sake of the example, I subclass UIScrollView):

```
@protocol MySubclassProtocol <UIScrollViewDelegate>
@required
-(void)myProtocolMethod;
@end

@interface MySubClass : UIScrollView

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MySubclassProtocol> delegate;
```

The most important detail here is the part between the <> after your protocol's name which, put in a simple manner, signals you're extending that protocol.
In your implementation, all you need to do then is:

```
@synthesize delegate;
```

And you're done.

Answer (score 3):

You need to extend the super protocol:

```
@protocol MYClassProtocol <SuperClassProtocol>
-(void)foo;
@end
```

after that **DON'T** (!!!) create the **@property** for the delegate otherwise you override the original delegate object, but simply override the method:

```
- (id<MYClassProtocol>)delegate
{
    return (id<MYClassProtocol>)[super delegate];
}
```

now you can use the delegate in the classic way:

```
[self.delegate foo];
[self.delegate someSuperClassDelegateMethod];
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that MySubClassMessage: is optional, you should be able to simple do a simple:

```
- (void) SomeMethod { 
  SEL delegateSelector = @selector(MySubClassMessage:);
  if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:delegateSelector]) { 
    [self.delegate performSelector:delegateSelector withObject:self];
  }
}
```

The complier should still check that the implementing class conforms to your protocol (or at least claim to in the header) and you won't get the error you described.

Comment: Given that it's optional, wouldn't this crash if the delegate doesn't implement the method?

Comment: @chuck, by itself, yes.  So you should first check that [self.delegate respondsToSelector: @selector (MySubClassMessage:)] evaluates to true.  I'll edit my answer to have the full method

Comment: there's a good point.  since my example says @optional it doesn't really matter if the object is conforming. I'm really interested in if it's not optional.  I'll take that out of the example. 

If I understand this correctly, isn't performSelector just avoiding the protocol conformance check here.  Wouldn't it still be possible to assign a non conforming delegate since the delegate accessors are actually defined in UITextViews super class?