# Is it possible to extend an protocol like this?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, protocols

I need to add some methods to the delegate protocol of my custom UITextField subclass. So I put this in the header:

```
@protocol MyTextFieldDelegate (UITextFieldDelegate)
- (void)textfieldDidSomething:(UITextField*)textField;
@end
```

Is this fine?

Comment: See [How to extend protocols / delegates in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732701/how-to-extend-protocols-delegates-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle I think it looks fine.  The only point I would make is I would write something like:

```
@protocol MyTextFieldDelegate (MyTextFieldDelegateExtras)
- (void)textfieldDidSomething:(UITextField*)textField;
@end
```

to distinguish it from the methods defined in the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol.

But really if you want to extend the protocol, then use:

```
@protocol MyTextFieldDelegate <UITextFieldDelegate>
- (void)textfieldDidSomething:(UITextField*)textField;
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

also when adding categories its suggested to add it in as a separate file with the naming convention of MyTextFieldDelegate+MyTextFieldDelegateExtras.h

Comment: maybe it'll be useful to show some code instead of just plain text.