# How to use method in a view that i put controls on it from subclass of one of that controls

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield, nsevent

I subclass a NSTextField and in subclass use an event method (keyUp),i want to call a method in main view (view that i put NSTextFiled on it) when user push Enter key.i use below code but don't how to call specific method in main view

```
- (void)keyUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSString *theArrow = [theEvent charactersIgnoringModifiers];
    unichar keyChar = 0;
    keyChar = [theArrow characterAtIndex:0];
    if ( keyChar == NSEnterCharacter )
    {
        //call method that exist in main view   
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.in main view set :  `textField.delegate=self;`

2.add `<NSTextFieldDelegate>` to mainview.h and subclass.h

3.use this code Instead of comment

```
if ( self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textFieldDidPressEnter:)] ) 
            [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(textFieldDidPressEnter:) withObject:self];
```

4.implement this method in mainview.m

```
-(void)textFieldDidPressEnter:(NSTextField *)txt
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it...

```
SEL sel = @selector(textFieldDidPressEnter:);

if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:sel]) {
    [self.delegate performSelector:sel withObject:self];
}
```

Then make sure the class you want to have this message is set as the delegate.  The more complete answer is to also declare textFieldDidPressEnter: as part of the delegate protocol.  [Here's a good resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732701/how-to-extend-protocols-delegates-in-objective-c) on how to do that.

Comment: can you explain where should i enter this code ?and how to set class as delegate?

Comment: sure.  right where you have the comment // call method that exist in main view.  Wherever the main view sets up the textField, you can say textField.delegate = self;  The "self" needs to be declared as conforming to <NSTextFieldDelegate>, and it needs to implement the method name I made up: textFieldDidPressEnter.  You can change that name as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textFieldDidPressEnter:)] ) 
    [(id)self.delegate textFieldDidPressEnter:self];
```

no need to use `performSelector:`