# How to create subclass of UITableViewController to extend capabilities?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm creating functionality in my UITableViewController that when a user taps a certain cell, a new cell slides out from beneath the taped cell with an input view (i.e. a picker view, etc).

Now I can create this behaviour in every table view controller over and over, but I'm wondering if instead there was a way that I could create a subclass of the table view controller that builds in this functionality automatically. My idea would involve creating a new protocol-delegate method that asks the delegate to return an input view for a given indexPath, then my subclass would automatically know to insert the inputView into a cell below the tapped cell.

The idea behind this kind of implementation is that the table view is built using the same data source and delegate methods as the table view, the only difference is that if the new delegate method returns an input view for a given index path, I would know to provide that functionality for the tapped cell.

So my question is how would I got about implementing this automatic cell insertion (inserting an input view) when a cell is tapped by subclassing UITableViewController?

I'm pretty familiar with iOS table views I just don't understands how I might extend the capabilities by creating a subclass. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using a category? It's tough to tell how complicated your issue really is, but my first instinct would be to just create a few extra methods in a UITableView category that you could then reference from any UITableView you use.

Comment: What I'm looking to do is to have this behaviour built-in without really having to do anything other that specifying an input view. I'm not sure how categories help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies in advance if this answer runs over stuff you're already familiar with - I wasn't sure what a good starting point would be.

So when we talk about tables on iOS we have three components - the `UITableView` itself, the `delegate`, and the `datasource` (I'm sure you know all of this already). To help us out, Apple provide a `UIViewController` subclass that manages the table view, delegate, and datasource - the `UITableViewController`.

You're obviously right to think that it's much clearer, saner, and better to have your 'automatic input cell insertion' logic in one place, rather than duplicating it across all the `UITableViewController` instances you use in your code.

*However*, and this is the key thing, the `delegate` and `datasource` methods *aren't* part of the `UITableViewController` - they're part of the `UITableView`. It sounds as if what you really want to do is subclass the *table view* and *extend* the delegate/datasource methods.

If that's confusing, think about it this way: ideally you want your improved, automatic input cell inserting, table view to work *anywhere* - table views can be used not just in table view controllers, but in any view controller (or view), and the delegate methods don't *have* to be implemented in the controller itself.

So what you probably want to do is subclass `UITableView`, modify the delegate and datasource to support your new input view methods ([if you're not sure about extending protocols, see this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732701/how-to-extend-protocols-delegates-in-objective-c)), and then - if you'd like - create a `UITableViewController` subclass that uses your table view subclass by default.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting answer. Can you give me an example of how I might intercept the datasource methods to inject my logic into them. So to be clear I want to be able to implement this new table view class using the same data source methods, I'm just not sure how to "intercept" the methods to inject in my own logic.