# Proper way to remove UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have a `settingsController`, which is a custom `UINavigationController`, that has to appear and disappear.

The XIB for it is in a storyboard and I have to keep track of it using `var settingsController` due to other house keeping purposes.

**Main View Controller:**

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    var settingsController : MySettingsNavigationController?

    func settingsButtonPressed () {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main Storyboard", bundle: nil)
        self.settingsController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Settings Navigation Controller") as? MySettingsNavigationController
        self.settingsController!.transitioningDelegate = self
        self.settingsController!.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        self.present(self.settingsController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    //Settings View Controller Transition Methods
    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
        let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from)
        let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to)
        if(self.isSettingsPresenting == true) {
            toViewController!.view.alpha = 1;
            toViewController!.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.001, y: 0.001);
            toViewController!.view.center = self.settingsButton.center

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0,
                           options: [.curveEaseIn], animations: { () -> Void in

                toViewController!.view.alpha = 1;
                toViewController!.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1);
                toViewController!.view.center = fromViewController!.view.center
                containerView.addSubview(toViewController!.view)

            }, completion: { (completed) -> Void in

                transitionContext.completeTransition(completed)

            })

        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0,
                           options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: { () -> Void in

                fromViewController!.view.alpha = 0;
                fromViewController!.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.01, y: 0.01);
                fromViewController!.view.center = self.settingsButton.center

            }, completion: { (completed) -> Void in
                //Two lines below added later to test..
                fromViewController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
                fromViewController?.removeFromParentViewController()
                transitionContext.completeTransition(completed)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**Settings Navigation Controller:**

```
class MySettingsNavigationController:  UINavigationController, UINavigationControllerDelegate
{
    .....

    func closeButtonPressed (_ sender: UIButton!) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            //Tried removing self in here...
        })
    }
}
```

**Issue:**

When I bring up `settingsController`, and close it, memory allocated by `settingsController` is never released; Somehow, `settingsController` is not getting deallocated.

Note:

Somehow I do have to:

1. Initiate the view controller from storyboard
2. Use custom animation transition
3. Not use a custom delegate (Since I cannot write a delegate to what
   is already a `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.  This could have given
   me the chance to call back to parent, `MainViewController` that it's
   ready to get removed

Comment: Does it work if you set `settingsController` to be `weak`?

Comment: I tried making it weak.  Somehow, it's still not getting removed properly.  If I log out settingsController, after the animation is completed, it still shows that it's alive..

Comment: Can you use a protocol to let the `MainViewController` know the `SettingsViewController` wants to dismiss, and dismissing `Settings` from there, and setting `settingsController` to nil in the completion?

Comment: The only way I know how to do this is make a SettingsViewController Delegate.  But Swift yells at me saying there's already a UINavigationControllerDelegate.

Comment: Is using a protocol possible with SettingsViewController?

Answer (score 3):

> Somehow, settingsController is not getting deallocated

- `var settingsController` looks like the probable culprit.
  Holding on a `ViewController` as a `var` object is *highly discouraged*.

> I have to keep track of it using 'var settingsController' due to other house keeping purposes.

- Evaluate utilising a `sharedHelper`- esque class that provides `controller` related attributes data or handles user interactions.
- No function, except the `settingsButtonPressed`(which alone should be responsible for invoking `settingsController`), should be designed such that it requires an instance of `settingsController` to execute. The data required by such functions can be extracted by multiple ways like `protocols`, `blocks`, `shared instances`, etc.

Comment: For example, if you have a settings screen that comes and goes, how would u see if its present at different occasions without a var ?

Comment: You can fire a `NSNotification` on presentation & dismissal of the _settings screen_. An interested object(probably a `ViewController`) can be an observer of this notification & perform related actions thereafter.

Comment: I guess the easy way out of above is to write a delegate in to settingsController.  However, since it's a UINavigationController, swift yells saying that it already has a delegate: UINavigationControllerDelegate.  Is there a way to still do that?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it would be an easy way out without the knowledge of implementation details. You can consider extending the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocol to provide the desired additional functionality. Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732701/how-to-extend-protocols-delegates-in-objective-c